# Prove/Disprove $f$ continuous iff $f[\mathring{A}]\supseteq\mathring{f[A]}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be 2 topological spaces. $f\colon X\to Y$ be a mapping. It is known that

$f$ is continuous iff

- $f[\bar{A}]\subseteq\overline{f[A]}$
- $f^{-1}[\bar{B}]\supseteq\overline{f^{-1}[B]}$
- $f^{-1}[\mathring{B}]\subseteq\overbrace{f^{-1}[B]}^\circ$

It is normally to ask that whether $f[\mathring{A}]\supseteq \overbrace{f[A]}^\circ$ can be added in this list?

Comment: If ° is the interior operator, it should follow the set, e.g., $f[A^\circ]\supseteq f[A]^\circ$.

Comment: Well, in many textbooks the little circle is placed above the set. This choice is painful with long expressions, though

Comment: @Siminore: Interesting. In $45$ years of reading them I’ve literally never seen that usage in a text in the U.S.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What Siminore said. In fact, I thought the reason it sometimes follows the set on this site was people's laziness to find out the correct latex command to put it on top of the set.

Comment: The function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = 1$ for $x > 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \leq 0$ has the property $f[A]^\circ = \emptyset \subseteq f[A^\circ]$  for all subsets $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ but is not continuous.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I agree that the circle-on-the-head is heavy notation, and often ugly. It shows up on some old textbooks, which were printed when the authors did not have to typeset the book themselves :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question: I really had no idea how it was going to go. The answer is that 
$f[A^\circ]\supseteq f[A]^\circ$ is neither sufficient nor necessary for $f$ to be continuous.

---

**Counterexample to Sufficiency**

Generalizing from an example given in the comments, just send $X$ discontinuously to a set with empty interior. Then every subset of $X$ goes to a set with empty interior as well, and the condition holds trivially. It's not hard to make the function discontinuous: as long as $X$ isn't discrete and its image intersects two different open sets (e.g. is at least two points of a Hausdorff space), we can do it.

---

**Counterexample to Necessity**

Let $f:(X,\tau)\rightarrow (X,\sigma)$ where $X=\{a,b,c\}, \tau=\{X,\{a\},\{b,c\}\},
\sigma=\{X,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}.$ Set $f(b)=f(c)=b, f(a)=a$. Then $f$ is continuous, since $f^{-1}(\{a,b\})=X,$ $f^{-1}(\{b\})=\{b,c\}$, and $f^{-1}(\{a\})=\{a\}$. But on the other hand $\{a,b\}$ has empty interior and is mapped to an open set $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: Many thanks. It's quite a unexpected result. Besides, the first counterexample seems has a bug: I think the result is $f[A^{\circ}]\subseteq f[A]^{\circ}$. e.g. $A=[0,1)$.

Comment: You're right. I've edited.

Comment: Ok, that's all right.